# Delete a bucket when you don't have access to it anymore on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am just starting to play around with amazons AWS S3 and I attempted to create a bucket that was private with a bucket policy.  The problem now is that it is so private, I can't do anything with it. (I know I don't know what I am doing) I can not access it or delete it or change the bucket policy back.  Here is the code I put into the bucket policy before the problem started.

```
   {
  "Id": "Policy1329364010722",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::jason-private",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway to delete the bucket?

Comment: Did you try deleting it through the AWS console?

Comment: Spencer, Yes I did try that and it says I don't have access to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a programmatical answer but it looks like some other users ran into the same issue. Let me know if the steps the Amazon Rep suggests are helpful.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57876

Comment: The suggestion of clicking on properties and make the changes in the permission tab is not an option for me because it will not show anything in the properties window at the bottom of the console.

Comment: Did you scroll down and try using the s3curl tool they recommend?

Comment: Yes.  I tried the s3curl.pl command line and it said permission denied.